# FMDB and datetime() function

Tags: ios, sqlite, datetime, fmdb

I'm having a few problems with dates and FMDB. I have a whole bunch of records with datetime values in them which I want to group by date/hour etc. Using a basic sqllite query tool, I have determined the correct sql syntax to use:

```
select strftime('%Y-%m-%d',datetime('2001-01-01',zentrydate || 'seconds','localtime')) as dteEntry...
```

The above works and the returned data is correct. However, when i try and execute the same using the FMDB wrapper, my result does not return the correct results. Any fields returned when using the datetime() function reads as NULL when i print it out to the console. Also, the query is not executing correctly either since only 1 record is returned, i know this is incorrect since i can execute the same query using my sqllite tools which returns the correct results.

Can anyone help me work out what I need to do? i only downloaded the FMDB lib a few weeks ago so should have a relatively recent version.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your reading the result set correctly with:
While ([rs next]) {

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just stumbled across it. A couple of thoughts:

1. When you say you have a bunch of datetime records, I'm not sure what that means within the context of SQLite, as there is no native datetime data type. (This is an alien concept for those of us approaching SQLite coming from other SQL engines.) It's either stored as a string, or as a numeric value. (See [SQLite Data Types](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html).)
2. Do I infer from your `zentrydate || 'seconds'`" syntax, that zentrydate is the number of seconds since 1/1/2001? If that's the case, you're missing a space before seconds, e.g. `zentrydate || ' seconds'`. If it's not the number of seconds since 1/1/2001, then I don't know what to make of this. Regardless, this would definitely cause FMDB to return NULL values.
3. You may want to reevaluate the use of `localtime`.

Bottom line, I suspect that this is *not* a FMDB issue, but a broader SQLite issue. If you're still having issues, let us know. I'm sure that you've found other ways to solve your issue by now, though.